# Edit account page without changing the base files

Tags: layout, sidebar, edit

I want to edit sidebar in account page and remove **recently product viewed** and **recently product compare**. I do this with editing the base files: `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\customer.xml`, I add these line in the `customer.xml`:

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
</customer_account>
```

But I want to do this without changing in the base files. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you copy this base file "customer.xml" in your theme layout folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy base file to your theme template

As per as magento `design fallback logic`,you need to copy `customer.xml`  from `base folder` and put `your  Current package template  layout folder`(app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourThemeTemplate/layout)

### By local.xml

Or create a layout local.xml file  at `your  Current package template  layout folder`(app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourThemeTemplate/layout)

out this code

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="right"><!-- may be left / right depend on theme --->
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
<reference>
</customer_account>
```